# How to elevate cross-sections in HEC-RAS 5.0.3?

Tags: elevation, cross-section, hec-ras

Then creating the cross sections in HEC-RAS it appears that all of the cross sections are in the same elevation. I have tried to change each elevation then creating each cross section, but I get elevations errors.

How do you create cross sections that show that there is a height difference between the first point and the second?

Comment: Can you  you provide more information about your data.  You start off  `Then creating the cross sections in` as if we already know the process you have taken and the data you are using.  What errors do you get?